# Golang: file extracted from tar throws permissions error

Tags: go

I've written the following code to tar a file, code works but strangely if I untar the archive the file permissions are gone so I can't read it unless I then chmod the file:

```
package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    c, err := os.Create("/path/to/tar/file/test.tar")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    tw := tar.NewWriter(c)

    f, err := os.Open("sample.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fi, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    hdr := &tar.Header{Name: f.Name(),
        Size: fi.Size(),
    }
    if err := tw.WriteHeader(hdr); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    r, err := ioutil.ReadFile("sample.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    if _, err := tw.Write(r); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    if err := tw.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: have you seen http://golang.org/pkg/archive/tar/#Header. There is user and group field in the header. Maybe you should fill  them with the current user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not preserving the original permissions of the file. You're manually creating a header, and specifying only the name and size.  Instead, use [`tar.FileInfoHeader`](http://golang.org/pkg/archive/tar/#FileInfoHeader) to build the header.

```
package main

import (
    "archive/tar"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    c, err := os.Create("/path/to/tar/file/test.tar")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    tw := tar.NewWriter(c)

    f, err := os.Open("sample.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fi, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    // create header from FileInfo
    hdr, err := tar.FileInfoHeader(fi, "")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    if err := tw.WriteHeader(hdr); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    // instead of reading the whole file into memory, prefer io.Copy
    r, err := io.Copy(tw, f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    log.Printf("Wrote %d bytes\n", r)
}
```

Also note that I used `io.Copy` to copy data from the file (an `io.Reader`) to the tar writer (an `io.Writer`).  This will work much better for larger files.

Also - pay special attention to this note from the docs:

> Because os.FileInfo's Name method returns only the base name of the file it describes, it may be necessary to modify the Name field of the returned header to provide the full path name of the file.

In this simple example, you're just using *sample.txt* so you shouldn't run into trouble.  If you wanted to preserve a directory structure in your tar, you may have to modify the `Name` field in the header.